# mathematical magic trick

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, number-theory, magic

Here’s a conversation that took place between two students.

A: Hey, want to see a magic trick?

B: Sure, how does it go?

A: Think of any number. Any nonnegative integer, I should say.

B: Okay.

A: Multiply it by 3.

B: Okay....

A: Now divide it by 2, and if you get a decimal, then round down.
Tell me if you rounded down or not.

B: I did have to round down.

A: Multiply it by 3 then divide it by 2 again. Again, tell me if you rounded down.

B: Okay, hang on... I did not have to round down this time.

A: Great, now just tell me: how many times does 9 go into this last number?

B: You want me to divide by 9?

A: Yes, just the quotient.

B: Um, the quotient is 4.

A: So your original number was 19.

B: That’s right! How did you do that? Let me think....

Can you figure out how it works?

Comment: According to your example, if B picks 19, B will report 4. If B picks 28, B will also report 4. How is A supposed to tell what B picked if B says 4?

Comment: Also, if B picks 0 or 1, the process will never end. Is this intended?

Comment: @Magma 0 x 1.5 = 0 and the process stops. But in any case 0 is not a positive integer, so is not a valid starting number.

Comment: right, only with 1 the process never ends

Comment: i have adjusted the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version of how/why it works:

> You are multiplying by 3 twice and later dividing by 9, so that’s essentially a wash. You are also dividing by 2 twice, so to recreate the original number from the final result, you need to multiply by 4 and then add some value to account for any fractional parts that were rounded away in the intermediate steps.
>
> Whether or not you rounded at each stage tells us what the original number was mod 4 (and therefore how much we have to add back at the end): if you didn’t have to round at all, it was 0 mod 4 (because the original number already contained two factors of 2 to divide by without leaving a fractional part); if you had to round down just the second time then it was 2 mod 4 (i.e. the original number was even but only had a single factor of 2 to divide out); if you had to round just the first time it was 3 mod 4, and if you had to round both times it was 1 mod 4,. So add the appropriate value to recreate the original number.
>
> In the example given, the final result was 4. We multiply this by 4 to get 16. Then, because they rounded down the first time but not the second, we add 3 to get the original number 19.